# How to send data from Kafka to Elastic Search using elk sink connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am new to kafka connect. I have a sink connector configured on a server for sending data from kafka queue to elastic search. I have created a project to produce data to kafka queue. This is happening successfully since I can see the data when I try to consume it using Kafka consumer. Now, what configurations do I need to do in my Java project so that the sink connector is started and the data goes from Kafka queue to elastic search. Or is this supposed to happen automatically since the connector config already points to elk url and other configurations are also in place?

Comment: did you start your Kafka Connect service? How did you start it? How did you configured the connector?

Comment: Connect does not run in "your Java Project". Removed Spring tag

Answer (score 1):

Kafka Connect is a service / task like Kafka Broker is a task, you need to make sure your Kafka Connect (Worker) is up and running
The connector you configure is running inside the Kafka Connect service...
Kafka Connect exposes REST API to check connector status